# Android tab layout error

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-tabhost, android-tabactivity

I created an app with 2 tabs using TabLayout...

I need to integrate that application with another application.But while i reach the tab page,its ending up with an error

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android/com.android.simphone.SimFoneDetailsActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a TabHost whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.tabhost'

I changed the id of the TabHost,but no use......Please any suggestions are welcome...

The xml portion of the code is also attached...

```
<TabHost 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:background="@drawable/bg_sim">
<LinearLayout 
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<TabWidget 
android:id="@+id/tabs" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TabWidget>
<FrameLayout 
android:id="@+id/tabcontent" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"></FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Comment: Plz put up the xml containing your tab and also the code where you have created the tabs in your code.

Comment: @Shubhayu xml code have been put...check it....thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<TabHost 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:background="@drawable/bg_sim">
<LinearLayout 
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<TabWidget 
android:id="@android:id/tabs" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TabWidget>
<FrameLayout 
android:id="@android:id/tabcontent" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"></FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Note that for tabs to work correctly you need to use this **@android:id/**

Comment: can you put up the code that u use to initialize the tab in your OnCreate() of the Activity?

Answer (score 1):

What's your layout xml code?
Do you write like this:

```
<TabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
......
</>
```

Comment: So would you like show more code, so others can refer the error

Comment: sure...i will post my xml code...is it enough ,or should i need to add-on anything else?

Comment: yeah, also it's better if you can show where the code run exception

Comment: the xml code is posted,as check the id;i changed it from what you referred...please see it...

Comment: your tabwidget and FrameLayout are wrong, they are should be <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs" .../> and <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent" .../>

Comment: Hey Subrussn90, what's the name of this layout xml, main.xml?